# Are open rays open sets in the usual topology

Tags: real-analysis

In the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, we know $(a,b)$ are open sets. But, how about $(-\infty, a ) $, are they also open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since they are the union of the open sets $(-n,a)$ for every $n \geq |a|$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$. In formulas $(-\infty ,a) = \bigcup_{n \geq |a|} (-n,a)$.

Comment: Thanks, so also $(a, \infty ) $ are open since $(a, \infty) = \bigcup_{n \geq |a| } (a, n ) $ correct ?

Comment: Yes. You can use this kind of argumentation for a lot of sets.